# How to add average trend line of different lines of each factor or categorical variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following plot produces three separate lines according to the number of gear. I want to add one more line that represents the average value of the three categories so that the plot may have four lines in total.

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_line(aes(x=mpg, y=drat, colour=factor(gear)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're looking for `geom_smooth`. You can change the underlying regression method with `method = ...`.

NB I've moved your x/y aesthetics into the main ggplot call.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=drat)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(gear))) +
  geom_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```r
+ stat_summary(aes(x=mpg, y = drat), fun = mean, geom = "line")
```

to your plot should do it.

The results are pretty ugly in this example, because it only averages the y-values measured *at a particular y value*, not the value of the linearly interpolated lines for each group ... it would work better for a data set where every group was represented at each value of x ...

If by "trend line" you mean a linear regression line including all the groups, then @tjebo's answer with `method = "lm"` would be more appropriate.